# Как используя gulp плагин browserSync сделать вывод ошибок sass?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Как используя gulp плагин browserSync сделать вывод ошибок sass?
вот конфиг

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){ 
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')  
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle:'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError)) 
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))  
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))  
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))  
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {  
    browserSync({  
        server: { 
            baseDir: 'app'  
        },
        notify: false  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`BrowserSync`, это не плагин для `gulp`, это полноценный `dev` сервер с возможностью авто обновления всех подключенных устройств, с помощью которого даже можно показывать результат клиентам.

`BrowserSync` никакого отношения не имеет к ошибкам компилятора `sass`.

Чтобы правильно обрабатывать любые ошибки при использовании `gulp` используют связку модулей -

- [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber)  - не позволяет `gulp` аварийно завершаться при возникновении ошибки.
- [gulp-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify) - красиво показывает ошибки выводя их в сплывающих окнах системы.

Конкретно в Вашем случаи нужно удалить следующую за `gulp.src` строку и на её место добавить ( естественно заранее подключив модули ) -

```
.pipe( plumber( { errorHandler: notify.onError( "ERROR: <%= error.message %>" ) } ) )
```